# VSCode extension for Javascript types

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Is there a VSCode extension that shows data type of a variable (like if we hover above that variable)? Presumably by detecting the type of a variable by looking at its initialization, and maybe even follow subsequent re-assignments? I know that using Typescript will give me great tooling which will do what I am seeking, but I don't want to use Typescript.

Answer (score 1):

No not really, that's the nature of dynamic programming. VS Code itself can sort of guess, but it's mostly based on frequent strings used within the file or directory.

The closest is JSDoc (which has more uses than just types, you should probably already be using this) and indirectly using Typescript in your plain .js files to help VS Code.

At the top of your files add this:

`// @ts-check`

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript#_type-checking-javascript